# scrolling is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to have the scrolling effect in my navbar. When scrolling is greater than 140, another nav should be shown and if less than 140 then transparent navbar should be shown. I have implemented the scroll function inside `componentDidMount` lifecycle. The scrolling effect works but not as expeccted. I have to scroll down multiple times to see the effect and when i scroll down to more than 140 and again scroll up, i still see the colored navbar insted of transparent navbar.

**Here is my code**

```
class Navbar extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrolling.bind(this));
  }

  handleScrolling(e) {
    let scrollTop = e.srcElement.body.scrollTop;
    if (scrollTop > 140) {
      if (this.el.className.indexOf("open") === -1) {
        console.log('not open');
        this.el.classList.add("open");
      } else {
        if (this.el.className.indexOf("open") > -1) {
          console.log('closed');
          this.el.classList.remove("open");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
  return (
    <div className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" ref={(el) => this.el = el}>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a className="logo" href="index.html"><img src={logo} alt="Logo" /></a>
        </div>
        <div className="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#home" className="scroll">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">DRIVER</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BRAND</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JOIN NOW</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SIGN IN</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default Navbar;
```

You can see the scrollbar is at the top and colored navbar is shown. It is when i am scrolling to top from bottom.

**Here is the screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Removing indexOf check solved the issue but i dont know why. Can anyone explain me, please?